# log4j2 - Cannot see spring logs

Tags: spring, log4j2

I have a j2ee application and I am not able to see the Spring logs In the log file
log file is defined in an Appender:

```
<RollingFile name="MyRollingFile"
```

File is created on the disk and I am able to see my application class log messages just fine

```
<Logger name="com.xerox.app" level="debug" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile"/>
</Logger>
```

[image: the HTML log produced]

Here is the logs dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="fileName">C:/appLogs/log/LogViewer.html</Property>
        <Property name="fileNamePattern">C:/appLogs/log/LogViewer%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.html</Property>
        <Property name="logPattern">%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="MyRollingFile" fileName="${fileName}" filePattern="${fileNamePattern}">
            <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8"  pattern="${logPattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.xerox.app" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">           
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I also tried to change Logger name to :

```
 logging.level.org.springframework.web
```

no success...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding log4j2 bridge jars?
Spring uses org.apache.commons.logging

See
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars
to select appropriate bridge jar.